# Why do electrons in a superconductor lack energy to produce "massive" photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics

My two questions are based around looking for a good, simple (if possible) explanation of the Cooper pair effect in superconductors.

I follow the idea that, in intuitive terms, "a Cooper Pair" combine so that each resistance ("push") felt by one electron is balanced by an equal and opposite ("pull") on the other member of the pair, so allowing unimpeded travel by the pair through the superconductor.

First question.  Is it best (or in fact the only way) to think of this concept in wave terms? If so, what would the general form of the wave function of a Cooper pair take? In other words, if we modelled the position of each electron as a wave packet, is there a relatively simple function that describes this paired situation and it's time evolution as it moves through the superconductor?

Second Question: Why do photons gain an "effective" mass in the BCS theory?  I can follow the idea that, if an effective photon mass **is** present, then because the electrons in a superconductor do not have enough energy to produce them, then no emission of photons occurs and this implies no resistance. I am just having difficulty trying to get a picture of why / how Cooper pairs lack the energy to produce retarding photons.

My current background is at basic Q.M level and if I have got concepts badly mixed up or more background is needed, (both of which are extremely likely possiblities), then simply telling me that or pointing out required background reading will be very useful answers in themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with a lot of my questions, I need a lot more background even to pose the question properly, but I think this link [Cooper Pairs](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/courses/phy4523/spring12/Sample%202.pdf) and the excerpts below have pointed me in the right direction.

In particular they have motivated me to do more basic background on Fermi-Dirac statistics before posting similiar questions.

I have included two excerpts from the above link which I hope to follow in greater depth after more background reading.

The penultimate line of the excerpt may provide an explanation to my question above:
*Why & how Cooper pairs lack the energy to produce retarding photons?* and also explain why low temperatures are so closely involved in the process behind superconductivity.

[image]
[image]